# Reduce network latency in spring boot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, ubuntu, networking

I'm working on a SpringBoot Application, I've created a rest API that saves a large JSON into a set of tables in the database and it is working really well on my local database.

However, when in the `application.properties` I change the `jdbc.url` to a **network IP** but it takes too much time.

I believe it is because of network latency.

How can I optimize the latency? My system is 16GB i5 on Ubuntu and my database is MySQL

Comment: you can do nothing much about network latency but one thing you can do is to optimize your sql operations like batching.

Comment: I am already doing the batching. All my insertions is in batches of 50

Comment: You need to first pinpoint the issue. Get the database queries application generates (inserts/updates) and run them directly using the db client program ( for ex. MySQL workbench) you are using and see how long it takes. If the latency is there, you need to optimize the queries and look at database differences. If that part is fast you can look at optimizing the application code

Answer (score 0):

Network latency depends on multiple things, you can check:

1. Network latency between web server and mysql host, you can perform a ping to check.
2. You connection pool configuration on your spring boot application.